# how to get icon for each file type listed on ftp server's directory

Tags: c#

I'm building my own ftp client application for windows OS using c#.i want to know how can to get icon for each file type listed on ftp server's remote directory.

Comment: Do you mean icon or thumbnail? In any case I don't think what you want is possible for all file extensions. If you want to create thumbnails you will have to download some part of the file to create it, unless you assign an icon per file extension.

Answer (score 1):

USe shell API to get the file type information.  Check the API SHGetFileInfo which can give you the file icon, description & attributes. Below is the link to it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Will that work for files in an FTP server? I thought that works only on the local file system and windows shared drives. If the FTP server is a Linux server, how would a client request such information?

Comment: Give only the filename, it will work. It doesn't try to read the file unless its a executable where the icon is embedded into the file.

Comment: thanks,it worked pretty well.